# How to find a number $n$ when $n$ mod $n_1$ and $n$ mod $n_2$ is given?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

For example:
suppose we need to find **x** given that **x mod 7 = 5** and **x mod 13 = 8**.

**x = 47** is a solution but needs hit and trial.

Is there any shortcut to calculate such number?

Comment: What you need is the Chinese remainder theorem. By calculating the inverses, there is an efficient method avoiding trial and error.

Comment: @Peter can you please provide link to some good article?

Comment: $x \mod 13 = 8$  implies $x = 13n + 8$ for some integer, $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if we are taking the moduli of pairwise coprime integers greater than $1$, then you can use the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

However for the case above, I will consider the definition of modular equivalence. That is, two integers are said to be congruent modulo $n$ if $n$ is a divisor of their difference.

$$x \equiv 5\pmod{7}\implies x=5+7k_{1}$$

for $k\in\mathbb Z$ and substituting into the second equation we obtain

$$x\equiv 8\mod{13}\implies5+7k_{1}\equiv8\mod{13}$$
$$\implies7k_{1}\equiv 3\pmod{13}$$

and then note that $7^{-1}\equiv 2\pmod{13},$ indeed $14\equiv 1\pmod{13}$. To compute these values, you can either use the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) or [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

Then we have

$$7k_{1}\equiv 3\pmod{13}$$
$$2\cdot 7k_{1}\equiv 2\cdot3\pmod{13}$$
$$k_{1}\equiv6\pmod{13}\implies k_{1}=6+13k_{2}$$

for $k_{2}\in\mathbb{Z}$ and substituting for $k_{1}$ we obtain the solutions to be given by

$$x=5+7k_{1}=5+7\left(6+13k_{2}\right)=47+91k_{2}$$

or $$x\equiv 47\pmod{91}$$

Comment: Or apply $13y=(2(7)-1)y$ and get the multiplier on 13 needs be $3$ the difference between the remainders.

Answer (score 0):

There exist a lot of ways to do this :

- Sequentially try values of $x$ (basic, 47 guesses maximum)
- Use the lowest congruence and work up in sequence( meh,13 guesses maximum )
- Use the highest congruence and work down sequence (okay 7 guesses maximum)
- Note if $x$ is odd the first congruence can only work at even multiples of $7$, and the second only at odd multiples of $13$. (cool)
- Use Chinese remainder theorem or extension ( typical)

Answer (score 0):

$x=\frac{5*13+8*7}{7+13}=121/20=121*41=47\mod{(7*13)}$

$x=m_1\mod{n_1}$
$x=m_2\mod{n_2}$
$x=m_3\mod{n_3}$
...
$x=m_n\mod{n_n}$

$$x=\frac{m_1/n_1+m_2/n_2+m_3/n_3+...m_n/n_n}{1/n_1+1/n_2+1/n_3+...1/n_n}\mod{(n_1*n_2*n_3...n_n)}$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).